# Tool-supported software release workflow

Tags: svn, maven, jenkins, workflow, release

We are currently in the process of setting up a tool-supported software release workflow.

Our current environment consists of the following:

- Jenkins build server
- Subversion repository
- Nexus Maven repository

The build server produces all kinds of different artifacts, some of which
are Java artifacts created by Maven and stored in the Nexus repository,
but also non-Java artifacts, which we currently have to store and manage manually.

Our goal is to create a software release which consists of several
heterogeneous components. The release configuration should define:

- the components which belong to it
- the exact version of these components
- the source code which was used to create these components

The release configuration should contain all relevant information
to understand and possibly reproduce the release at a later time.

A tool implementing this workflow should also support quality assurance 
by allowing the release to be tagged as unstable, testing or stable.

So the question is: are there any tools which support the described
workflow?

Comment: You have all the component parts to build such as system, you just need to configure the project builds in Jenkins. Use the M2 Releases plugin to leverage Maven's ability to manage your release life-cycle (Including tagging of source code in subversion)

Comment: Problem is, that a) maven doesn't cover the non-java artifacts and b) the it's not (easily) possible without a complex repository setup to promote artifacts between qa-testing and release

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview), which is a tool from Atlassian. With JIRA it is easy to track issues, releases, etc. Too many features to mention here, but I suggest you check out the link.

Comment: how would you use jira to automatically manage software artifacts?!?

Comment: Using [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview/release-management)

Answer (score 0):

Opt for a generic package repository (rpm, deb) instead of a Java artifact repo. The release configuration now becomes a first-class package that states dependencies (components that belong to it) and their versions. As for the source, you could choose to also create [source packages](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-miscellania-srpms.html). If you are just interested in source traceability, you could add custom metadata to the package spec e.g. add something parseable to the description. [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki) is a popular tool for creating these packages.

Related links:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/create-your-own-yum-repository/609

https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-yum-plugin